# Referring a variable with a variable in java

Tags: java

I have got into a strange strange situation. I have 3 sets of strings like this

```
String set1q1="something";    //associated with randomNum=1
String set1q2="something";
String set1q3="something";
String set1q4="something";
... and so on

String set2q1="something";    //randomNum=2
String set2q2="something";
String set2q3="something";
String set2q4="something";
... and so on

String set3q1="something";    //randomNum=3
String set3q2="something";
String set3q3="something";
String set3q4="something";
... and so on
```

All these strings are initialised only once. Now in my program i generate a random number between 1-3. I converted this random number into a string and stored it into a string called set.

```
String set=randomNum.toString();
```

Now next intead of using "if-else" to send the data(if randomnum=1 send set1q1-5, if randomnum=2 then send set2q1-5), I want the appropriate data to be sent using one line.

For example: if random no 2 is chosen then set2q1 has to be sent where the "2" in between is has to be the value of "set"(which is defined above).

```
set"set"q1    //where set can be 1,2,3
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: why don't you use arrays or lists?

Comment: Why not use an array to hold each "set" and simply use the index?

Comment: @deporter: I will try lists. It seems to be a good Idea. Will HashMap also be appropriate?

Comment: @user1139023 no hashmap! use arraylist or array.

Comment: @user1139023 how will you populate the hashmap? manually? it is not a good practice for your problem, use list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are asking for is not possible;<sup>1</sup> it's just not the way Java works.  Why don't you just use an array, or a collection?

```
List<List<String>> allTheStrings = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

List<String> myStrings = null;

// Add a subset
myStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
myStrings.add("something");
myStrings.add("something");
myStrings.add("something");
allTheStrings.add(myStrings);

// Add another subset
myStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
myStrings.add("something");
myStrings.add("something");
myStrings.add("something");
allTheStrings.add(myStrings);


...

// Obtain one of the strings
String str = allTheStrings.get(1).get(2);
```

---

<sub>1. Except in the case where these variables are members of a class, in which case you could use reflection.  But really, don't.</sub>

Comment: but did you get the question, he doesn't mention about his desire to use arrays or lists.he is asking a "varying portion" in the name of a variable. ok?

Comment: @deporter: I indeed got the question.  But this is the correct answer; the OP needs to be informed that what he/she wants is not how Java works.

Comment: +1: This is what should be done, a data structure. Although the OP asked about pseudo-reflection, as @OliCharlesworth mentioned - dont. A `HashMap` could also work here too to meet the OPs requirements.

Comment: @Deco: Even I was thinking of HashMaps. Seems to be a good Idea. thank you . I will try that also.

Comment: @user1139023: There's little value in a HashMap here.  HashMaps are useful when your indexes are non-contiguous, or are a complex data-type.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: then is using maps a better Idea?

Comment: @user1139023: I don't think you need any kind of map if you have already have an integer index available.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth : What if I need to refer to the a particular value with a string, not a number as in the case of list. Then is there any option any other than hash map? -retrieve a string by giving a string as an input.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. Local variable identifiers are converted to numbers (stack offsets) during compilation. But you should use arrays or collections anyway

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to index Strings by two indices. You should use a two-dimensional String array: `String[][] strings`. You may then access the desired string with `strings[n][m]`

Or you can achieve the same effect with a `List<List<String>> strings` if you need the dimensions of your 2D array to grow dynamically. You'd access the value you need with `strings.get(n).get(m)`

If you *really* want to access your strings by a composed name such as `set2q1`, then you just need a `Map<String, String> strings`. Then you'd access each value with `strings.get("set" + m + "q" + n)`

Comment: Does using Map have any side affects - like consumer memory or something like that. Basically I am asking was hash map meant for this - accessing your object using a string to refer to it.

Comment: The overhead is minimal. The collection classes all have their distinct qualities and capabilities. You can use a Map anytime you wish to create a set of references from one domain to another. For example `Map<Person, Address> workplaceAddresses` or `Map<Integer, Element> periodicTableOfElements` etc.

Answer (score 0):

looks to me you should look into arrays, like this:

```
String[] strings = new String[]{"xxx", "yyy", "zzz"};
String string = strings[randomNumber];
```

Answer (score 0):

create an arraylist instead and reference using the list index

Comment: he is asking a varying portion in the name of a variable. of course arrays should be preferred. but the question is different. i will downvote it, please remove.